# I Want To Add A Border Line In My Image In HTML File

Tags: html, css, image

I Was Browsing Many Other Developer's Portfolio And Came Across A Portfolio Where The Profile Image Has A Background With Some Solid Line.
[You can Check It Here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBS4s.png) Or You Can Visit Site https://brittanychiang.com/.

I Also Wanted This Type Of Background In My Image Too. Please Help Me.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.about {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #161922;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.about .content img {
  height: auto;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.text {
  width: 550px;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.content {
  width: 1280px;
  max-width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.text h1 {
  color: #ffcc74;
  font-size: 85px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.text h5 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.text p {
  color: #c0c4d4;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

button {
  background-color: #ffcc74;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #ffcc74;
  color: #ffcc74;
  transition: .4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1180px) {
  .about {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 70px 0px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .about .content img {
    margin-bottom: 35px;
  }
  .text h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="about">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="">
    <!-- Image Profile -->
    <div class="text">
      <h1>About Me</h1>
      <h5>Web Developer</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid molestiae iste accusantium rerum magnam reprehenderit possimus voluptatem fugiat, fugit recusandae, animi ipsum. Esse, similique! Consequatur delectus vel ab eos eveniet?</p>
      <button>Hire Me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Please Help Me To DO So!!!!

Comment: You're probably going to need to do the border in a container div, then do a transform on the image itself

Comment: Use your browser dev tools on that site to see how they've done it. It's simply an after pseudo element on the relevant div. The after is same dimensions as the image but positioned with an offset of 20px in both top and left and with a border that greeny color. In general for this sort of visual addition don't add actual elements to your DOM but stick with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this? Box shadows instead of borders.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.about {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #161922;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.about .content img {
  height: auto;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.text {
  width: 550px;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.content {
  width: 1280px;
  max-width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.text h1 {
  color: #ffcc74;
  font-size: 85px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.text h5 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.text p {
  color: #c0c4d4;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

button {
  background-color: #ffcc74;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #ffcc74;
  color: #ffcc74;
  transition: .4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1180px) {
  .about {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 70px 0px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .about .content img {
    margin-bottom: 35px;
  }
  .text h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
}

img {
  box-shadow: 30px 30px 0 -10px #161922, 30px 30px 0 0 cyan;
}
```

```html
<section class="about">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="">
    <!-- Image Profile -->
    <div class="text">
      <h1>About Me</h1>
      <h5>Web Developer</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid molestiae iste accusantium rerum magnam reprehenderit possimus voluptatem fugiat, fugit recusandae, animi ipsum. Esse, similique! Consequatur delectus vel ab eos eveniet?</p>
      <button>Hire Me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.about {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #161922;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.about .content img {
    height: auto;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    display: block; /*DEMO PURPOSE*/
    background: #ff0; /*DEMO PURPOSE*/
}
/*added css*/
.about .content .img_wrapper {
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 30px -15px navy;
    transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.645,0.045,0.355,1);
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.about .content .img_wrapper::before {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color:navy;
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
.about .content .img_wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.645,0.045,0.355,1);
    border: 2px solid green;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.about .content .img_wrapper:hover::after, 
.about .content .img_wrapper:focus::after {
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
/*added css*/
.text {
    width: 550px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.content {
    width: 1280px;
    max-width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.text h1 {
    color: #ffcc74;
    font-size: 85px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.text h5 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.text p {
    color: #c0c4d4;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 28px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}

button {
    background-color: #ffcc74;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

button:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #ffcc74;
    color: #ffcc74;
    transition: .4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1180px) {
    .about {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        padding: 70px 0px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    .about .content img {
        margin-bottom: 35px;
    }

    .text h1 {
        font-size: 60px;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/css/about.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="about">
        <div class="content">
        <div class='img_wrapper'> <!--added-->
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="">
 <!-- Image Profile -->
            </div> <!--added-->
            <div class="text">
                <h1>About Me</h1>
                <h5>Web Developer</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid molestiae iste accusantium rerum
                    magnam reprehenderit possimus voluptatem fugiat, fugit recusandae, animi ipsum. Esse, similique!
                    Consequatur delectus vel ab eos eveniet?</p>
                    <button>Hire Me</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Play with the values until you're happy...

Comment: btw, thank you for whoever downvoted. my answer may not be "useful" but it was intended to give a way for the OP to learn how to get the result he wanted on his own ANd I even included the hover effect. so again HUGE THANK YOU!

Comment: It is probably missing some infos about css you used ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example of your requirement

```css
img,
.border {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.border {
  border: 5px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://doggowner.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/brown-dog-names-cover-image.jpg" </img>
  <div class="border"></div>
</div>
```